# How to Join two tables in codeigniter in a single column

Tags: php, sql, mysql, codeigniter

I want to Join the two tables in CodeIgniter in a single column. For example, There is table A as shown in images

[image]

Table B

[image]

Desired Result After Joining Table A and Table B

[image]

Comment: Any relation between these two tables?

Comment: I don't want to compare these tables

Comment: I way to to get records separately and then merge the result

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `union`

```
select name from tableA
union 
select name from tableB
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$tableA = $this->db->select('name')->get_compiled_select('tableA');
echo $tableA;
$tableB = $this->db->select('name')->get_compiled_select('tableB');
echo $tableB;
$tableAB = $this->get_compiled_select($tableA.' UNION '.$tableB);
echo $tableAB;
$query = $this->db->query($tableAB);
```

Output:

```
SELECT name FROM tableA
SELECT name FROM tableB
SELECT name FROM tableA UNION SELECT name FROM tableB
```

OR:

```
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT name FROM tableA UNION SELECT name FROM tableB");
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$result1 = $this->db->get('TableA');

$result2 = $this->db->get('TableB');
```

If you want to merge only specific columns use `select()`

```
$this->db->select('name');
$result1 = $this->db->get('TableA');

$this->db->select('name');
$result2 = $this->db->get('TableB');
```

And now merge these two records

```
$combine = array_merge($result1, $result2);
```

Read more about [array_merge()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php)

Answer (score -1):

select Name from TableA Union select Name from TableB